# How to set the "chunk size" of read lines from file read with Python subprocess.Popen() or open()?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, chunking

I have a fairly large text file which I would like to run in chunks. In order to do this with the `subprocess` library, one would execute following shell command:

```
"cat hugefile.log"
```

with the code:

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("cat hugefile.log", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = task.stdout.read()
```

Using `print(data)` will spit out the entire contents of the file at once. How can I present the number of chunks, and then access the contents of this file by the chunk size (e.g. chunk = three lines at a time).

It must be something like:

```
chunksize = 1000   # break up hugefile.log into 1000 chunks

for chunk in data:
    print(chunk)
```

The equivalent question with Python `open()` of course uses the code

```
with open('hugefile.log', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
```

How would you `read_data` in chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a file, you can iterate on the file handle (no need for subprocess to open `cat`):

```
with open('hugefile.log', 'r') as f:
     for read_line in f:
        print(read_line)
```

Python reads a line by reading all the chars up to `\n`. To simulate the line-by-line I/O, just call it 3 times. or read and count 3 `\n` chars but you have to handle the end of file, etc... not very useful and you won't gain any speed by doing that.

```
with open('hugefile.log', 'r') as f:
     while True:
        read_3_lines = ""
        try:
           for i in range(3):
               read_3_lines += next(f)
        # process read_3_lines
        except StopIteration:  # end of file
            # process read_3_lines if nb lines not divisible by 3
            break
```

With `Popen` you can do exactly the same, as a bonus add `poll` to monitor the process (no need with `cat` but I suppose that your process is different and that's only for the question's purpose)

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("cat hugefile.log", shell=True,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = task.stdout.readline()
    if line == '' and task.poll() != None: break

rc = task.wait()   # wait for completion and get return code of the command
```

Python 3 compliant code supporting encoding:

```
    line = task.stdout.readline().decode("latin-1")
    if len(line) == 0 and task.poll() != None: break
```

Now, if you want to split the file into a given number of chunks:

- you cannot use `Popen` for obvious reasons: you would have to know the size of the output first
- if you have a file as input you can do as follows:

code:

```
import os,sys
filename = "hugefile.log"
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
nb_chunks = 1000
chunksize = filesize // nb_chunks

with open(filename,"r") as f:
   while True:
      chunk = f.read(chunksize)
      if chunk=="":
          break
      # do something useful with the chunk
      sys.stdout.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What is a priori I didn't know about three lines, but I just wanted the file split into `10**7` chunks?

Comment: you mean chunks of 10**7 bytes? and do you need Popen or not ? is your real-life case using `cat` or that's just for the simplicity of the question?

Comment: I mean split the file into 10**7 sections, without worrying about byte size. In the example above, `nb_chunks` is 1000 bytes---what if we are parsing rows sized 750 bytes each, could some rows be cut off? I need Popen(), yes. Cat is a simple example

Comment: It appears we have to know the correct number of bytes in `chunksize` given our file, if we want to do line-by-line work.

Comment: What is `rc = task.wait()` used for?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang if you need `Popen` and you have to know the size of your output, then you're stuck with either predicting it to compute chunk size or redirect output to a file within the Popen command and read that file by chunks afterwards. Note that lines are not taken in considerations because lines can have variable sizes in the general case of a text file.

Comment: It reads one line in an infinite loop, stopped when the process terminates. It's not hanging, it's working. but if you concatenate a string like `buffer += line` you'll have big performance problems. You have to store the lines in a list and join the list afterwards to prevent a lot of reallocs (strings are not very good with += performance-wise)

Comment: As lines can have variable length, what about row? How could you do `for row in f:` with `Popen()`?

Comment: a row is another word for a line... We could read char-by-char if we know which char is "terminating" the chunk. That is totally possible. `c = task.output.read(1)`